# How to send an array in an HTML post request with Django

Tags: arrays, django, forms, post, django-forms

I've got an array of values from a checklist:

```
{% for groups in groupList %}
    <tr>
        <td id="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check_{{groups.GroupID}}">
        </td>
    <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

note this is just a snippet of a larger table. this is the relevant data though.

I need to take all checked items in the table and extract the `groups.GroupID` into an array and pass this to somewhere (presumably a view) where I can use the data to edit a model instance.

I know how to get the data to an array just fine, but I'm not sure how to approach passing the data on. Possibly a form but I'm not sure how I would implement this to be attached to a view and also pass an array.

Answer (score 5):

Use **request.POST.getlist:**

eg:

```
for array_obj in request.POST.getlist('check'):
    # code
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

Comment: This looks like what I need! Do you know how I would include an array in my post request?

Comment: I haven't been able to test it yet as I'm not sure how to include the array in my post request